# how to stop a timer in setInterval by click then resume by click again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I am new to react, I am trying to write a react component, component has several features.

1. user can input a random number, then number will be displayed in the
   page too.
2. implement a button with text value 'start', once click the button,
   the number value displayed will reduce one every 1second and the
   text value will become 'stop'.
3. continue click button, minus one will stop and text value of button
   will become back to 'start'.
4. when number subtract to 0 will automatically stop itself.

I have implemented the first and second feature. but when I try to click stop to stop number from reducing 1, it does not work.

I am wondering since I used `type=true/false` to indicate the state of type is start or stop. Because in the start state, number should automatically reduce 1. And on the stop state, reducing 1 should stop. So, the timer function should accurate according to the state of type.

Also I am not sure if I used `clearInterval` method right.

I really appreciate if someone could give me a hand.

code is here:

```js
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          details: [{ id: 1, number: "" }],
          type: false
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }
      changeNumber = (e, target) => {
        this.setState({
          details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
            if (detail.id === target.id) {
              detail.number = e.target.value;
            }
            return detail;
          })
        });
      };

      handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          type: !prevState.type
        }));
        if (this.state.type === false) {
          var myTimer = setInterval(
            () =>
              this.setState({
                details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
                  if (detail.id) {
                    detail.number = parseInt(detail.number) - 1;
                  }
                  return detail;
                })
              }),
            1000
          );
        } else if (this.state.type === true) {
          clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.state.details.map(detail => {
              return (
                <div key={detail.id}>
                  Number:{detail.number}
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    onChange={e => this.changeNumber(e, detail)}
                    value={detail.number}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => this.handleClick()}
                    value={this.state.type ? "stop" : "start"}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `var myTimer` outside of the `handleClick()` function.

So it's something like:

```
var myTimer;

...

handleClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          type: !prevState.type
        }));
        if (this.state.type === false) {
          myTimer = setInterval(
            () =>
              this.setState({
                details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
                  if (detail.id) {
                    detail.number = parseInt(detail.number) - 1;
                  }
                  return detail;
                })
              }),
            1000
          );
        } else if (this.state.type === true) {
          clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
      };
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but I am still a bit confusing, could you tell me where exactly I should declare var myTimer?

Comment: I figured thanks for the help, but may I ask why should I declare var myTimer outside the function scope?

Comment: Because it needs to be a higher scope. So that when you call the same function again `myTimer` still has the interval (so you can clear it) . When you declare it inside the function, each function call creates a new instance of `myTimer`. So it cannot clear the old one